# Fix marvel ata bug on macbook air 6.2

Tags: macbook, macbook-air

I have been using ubuntu 14.04 on my macbook air 6.2 for a while now and pretty much everything is working as it should. There is one major problem with the marvel ata chipset though. Every once in a while the cpu will come under heavy load :

```
ata1: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x10000 action 0xe frozen
ata1: irq_stat 0x00400000, PHY RDY changed
ata1: SError: { PHYRdyChg }
ata1: hard resetting link
ata1: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
ata1.00: unexpected _GTF length (8)
ata1.00: unexpected _GTF length (8)
ata1.00: configured for UDMA/33
ata1: EH complete
```

The problem is also mentioned in the archlinux macbook wiki : https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MacBook - It links to a bug report with some discussion which however does not lead to a real solution/conclusion. I tried the hacks discussed there but did not succeed.

There is also a bug report over at launchpad but it does not offer any solutions : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1318218

Has anyone managed to solve this ? If so please let me know how.